# CKEDITOR removing only asp.net tags problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, ckeditor

In controller level i used `[ValidateInput(false)]`
and `ValidateRequest="false"` in the view.

Everything is fine except CKEDITOR removing <% %> tags.

Is there any other configuration i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent CKEditor from removing content, the `protectedSource` setting will do what you need. [**Manual & examples**](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.protectedSource)

Comment: thank you! exact solution was: 
config.protectedSource.push( /<%[\s\S]*?%>/g )